# Strange results from Google places autocomplete for sequence of repeating letters

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

This call https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=qqqqqqq (plus your key) returns addresses like 'qqqqqqqqqq, Florida, USA' and 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq - Luizote de Freitas, Uberlândia - State of Minas Gerais, Brazil'. I understand that QQQ might be a valid name, but qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq? And it works the same way for any sequence of repeating letters or numbers.

Ok, let's say this is google having bad data. But how to explain results for 'www': 'Best Buy, Middlesex Turnpike, Burlington, MA, USA', 'Acton Toyota of Littleton, Great Road, Littleton, MA, USA'? I do not see any sane correlation between 'www' and the results.

You can see similar behaviour in google maps, so it's not just autocomplete API.

Any theories?

Answer (score 0):

When I execute request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=www&key=MY_API_KEY` from my location I get really weird predictions as well

- Montpellier, France (place ID ChIJsZ3dJQevthIRAuiUKHRWh60, type locality)
- Berlin, Germany (place ID ChIJAVkDPzdOqEcRcDteW0YgIQQ, type locality)
- Hamburg, Germany (place ID ChIJuRMYfoNhsUcRoDrWe_I9JgQ, type locality)
- Munich, Germany (place ID ChIJ2V-Mo_l1nkcRfZixfUq4DAE, type locality)
- Vienna, Austria (place ID ChIJn8o2UZ4HbUcRRluiUYrlwv0, type locality)

[image]

Note all of them have locality type, and indeed it smells like a bug, because I cannot see how on earth the text 'www' might match these predictions. Apparently, something is broken on Google backend and leads to the strange behavior in places autocomplete.

I can confirm that I can see this problem on Google Maps web site as well

[image]

At this point I believe the best option for us is [sending a feedback](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612) to Google Maps team and hope they will fix it soon.